# Using AND within a CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I am trying to add a `CASE WHEN` to the following *working* statement:

```
Select ...
From...
Where 
    d.name like @filter and d.flags & 0x0F <> 0
```

I have a situation where I wish to filter in less if the user sets the `BIT @showHidden` parameter to true.  This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT...        
FROM...
WHERE
d.name like 
    CASE WHEN @showHidden = 'true' THEN
        @filter
    ELSE
        @filter and d.flags & 0x0F <> 0
```

I am getting the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'and'.

Is it possible to have an `AND` within a `CASE WHEN`?

Comment: Can someone explain what is wrong about the way I asked my question that caused someone to vote it down?   I will edit my question to fix any problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT...        
FROM...
WHERE d.name like @filter 
  and ( @showHidden = 'true' -- show everything 
      OR 
        d.flags & 0x0F <> 0  -- check if name should be hidden
      )
```

Comment: I prefer this answer as it doesn't really need to use `CASE`, although a bit more of an explanation might be useful.

Comment: This works.  However, I do not completely understand it.  Why is the `d.flag & 0x0F <> 0)` only added when `@showHidden` is not true?

Comment: I think I understand... If `@showHidden = 'true` is equivalent to true, then the statement in parenthesis is finished.  If it is equivalent to false, then we continue to execute the part following `OR`.

Answer (score 4):

A `CASE` statement is properly ended with an `END`

```
SELECT...        
FROM...
WHERE
d.name like 
    CASE WHEN @showHidden = 'true' THEN
        @filter
    ELSE
        @filter 
    END and d.flags
```

If you would like to add the criteria in the WHEN the proper way to do it would be:

```
SELECT...        
FROM...
WHERE
d.name like 
    CASE WHEN @showHidden = 'true' and d.flags THEN
        @filter
    ELSE
        @filter 
    END
```

You may have many cases ofcourse:

```
SELECT...        
FROM...
WHERE
d.name like 
    CASE 
        WHEN Condition1 AND Condition2 THEN
            @filter1
        WHEN Condition3 AND Condition4 THEN
            @filter2
        WHEN Condition5 THEN
            @filter3
        ELSE
            @filter4
    END
```

`ELSE` is there to make sure you get a value if no condition is met.

**UPDATE**

In my answer i was trying to give some info on how CASE works though not really answering the whole question.

If you want an example of how to use `CASE` in this and you want the @filter to work only if @showHidden is true then:

```
d.name like 
    CASE 
        WHEN @showHidden = 'true' THEN @filter
        ELSE d.name
    END
```

So if `@showHidden` then `d.name` must be like the `@filter` else it must be like `d.name` (always true).

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize I was missing the `END`.  The first block of code given makes the `d.flags` part be added no matter what.  I wish for that part to only be added if `@showValue` is not true.  Again, your answer was helpful, thanks!